# Finding SE in the hypothesis testing of two proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, proportion

My question relates to **p. 645 top-right column of [THIS PAPER](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/retropower_final.pdf).** The authors say if there are two independent proportions, `prop1 = .56` and `prop2 = .48` and the `p.value` from (hypothesis) testing of the difference between these two proportions is `.015`, then **solving for standard error of difference** (`SE`) gives **.033** or **3.3%**.

But based on my simple calculations, `SE` must become **.0368** or **3.68%**. Am I missing anything here?

**Here is an R code showing how I arrived at SE = .0368:**

```
   prop1 = .56
   prop2 = .48
 p.value = .015
 z = qnorm(p.value, lower.tail = F)
 SE = (prop1 - prop2) / z       #### SE becomes .0368, right? ####
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have computed the p-value on a one-tailed test. They have done it on a two-tailed test. Your penultimate line should be `z = qnorm(0.015/2, lower.tail = FALSE)`

Comment: Dear Tim, Would please help me with [**This Question**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295857/how-to-check-confidence-interval-accuracy-on-a-proportion-from-a-binomial-experi)?